# Creating controllers hierarchy with @RestController (spring boot application)

Tags: spring-boot, hierarchy, spring-restcontroller

I want to create an hierarchy in my spring boot application controllers. Meaning: when requesting a path in one controller he will return the next controller.
It doesn't work...

In the example I created I expected to answer url:

- **/v1/notifications/test - should work**
- */v1 - shouldn't work*
- */v1/notifications - shouldn't work*
- */test - shouldn't work*
- *etc...*

This is what I did so far:
**Controller root:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class BaseController {

    @Autowired
    BaseControllerV1 baseControllerV1;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/v1")
    public BaseControllerV1 getBaseControllerV1(){
        return baseControllerV1;
    }
}
```

**Controller child:**

```
@RestController
public class BaseControllerV1 {
    @Autowired
    NotificationsControllerV1 notificationsControllerV1;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/notifications")
    public NotificationsControllerV1 getNotificationsControllerV1() {
        return notificationsControllerV1;
    }
}
```

**Controller grandchild:**

```
@RestController
public class NotificationsControllerV1 {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = "application/json")
    public String getTest(){
        return "{test: ok}";
    }    
}
```

Comment: Nor will it ever work... That is not how controllers work.

Comment: Do you want to create an api which has dynamic versioning ?

Comment: If there is a solution for dynamic versioning it will be good as well, but my main issue is creating a hierarchy in the path

Comment: In Jersy there is controllers hierarchy....